# Strpos - empty needle in Zend HTTP.php

Tags: magento-1.9, zend-framework, base-url

Since upgrading our Magento 1.8.0.0 to 1.9.2.1 I have noticed that we're getting hundreds of errors in the log file:

`2015-11-11T16:20:01+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: strpos(): Empty needle  in home/directory/public_html/lib/Zend/Controller/Request/Http.php on line 508`

Having had a look at the file, I can see:

```
if (0 === strpos($requestUri, $baseUrl)) {
  // full $baseUrl matches
  $this->_baseUrl = $baseUrl;
  return $this;
}

if (0 === strpos($requestUri, dirname($baseUrl))) {
  // directory portion of $baseUrl matches
  $this->_baseUrl = rtrim(dirname($baseUrl), '/');
  return $this;
}
```

The last thing I want to do is edit this core file to make a cheap fix. Does anybody know what could be the cause of this problem? My base URL is obviously set do I don't understand what could be causing the issue!

Comment: The given code snippet has not changed between [Zend Framework 1.11.1](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/1.8.0.0/lib/Zend/Controller/Request/Http.php#L501) and [Zend Framework 1.12.10](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/1.9.2.1/lib/Zend/Controller/Request/Http.php#L505) so it is not the library causing trouble. You need to have a look at (and provide) the full stack trace.

Comment: I know it can't be a problem with the framework because we have another website running the same version of Magento that isn't receiving such errors. The full error is `2015-11-12T15:40:01+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: strpos(): Empty needle  in /home/directory/public_html/lib/Zend/Controller/Request/Http.php on line 508
2015-11-12T15:40:01+00:00`.

Answer (score 2):

In my case the exact same error occurs every minute, on the minute. It seems the problem lies with core_email_queue_send_all, as this is the only job that is called every minute.

Somehow, but I am yet unsure why, the error message is caused by the way the cron job in Magento is called. I tested this in version 1.9.2.2

Starting cron by a call to cron.sh reproduces the error:

`sh public_html/cron.sh > /dev/null`

while calling cron.php directly does not cause the problem, using the following call:

`wget -O /dev/null -q http://www.myserver.nl/cron.php > /dev/null`

Comment: I'm just ignoring the errors for now and occasionally deleting my system.log file when it gets too big. I would change my cron to point to the .php file instead, but the .sh file is there to make sure that a cron isn't already running.

Comment: I have also tried using aoe_schedulers scheduler_cron.sh, but without success. You mentioned you have two servers, one with and the other without the issue. Are you using different calls to cron there also?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, I search on web and I found a potential solution. It seems correct

I modified /magento_root/cron.sh at line 39

PHP_BIN=`which php` => PHP_BIN=`which php-cli`

Source: 
https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_Scheduler/issues/233

EDIT : I made the change yesterday, and today I had 3 new orders, but no mail was sent. So I edit back and I received my mails. **So my solution seems NOT correct !**

Comment: I did see that link on GitHub a while ago, but implementing the change didn't fix the problem for me at the time. I've just realised that I was trying to implement this change into `scheduler_cron.sh` rather than `cron.sh` - so that's why it wasn't working!

Comment: it stops my cron from working.

Comment: Yeah it still stops my cron working as well because php-cli isn't even a command.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue for a while didn't pay too much attention to it although i knew it was related to cron as it appeared every 5 minutes, same as my cron was configured to run. Today i decided to have it resolved and i fixed it by going to CLI of my server and typing: whereis php. It came back with a bunch of php possibilities so i took the most generic one:  /usr/bin/php and in cron.sh i changed PHP_BIN=which php to PHP_BIN='/usr/bin/php'. Notice the quotations. Error wet away. I had some other errors in there and surprisingly they seem to have gone away as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
Error:
2017-12-29T04:20:02+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: strpos(): Empty needle in /home/hillcountry/public_html/lib/Zend/Controller/Request/Http.php on line 508
2017-12-29T04:20:02+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: strpos(): Empty needle in /home/hillcountry/public_html/lib/Zend/Controller/Request/Http.php on line 514
```

Comment: This problem is in defintion of base URL, because is running on cron script.

Possible solution: I think the possible solution is add the environment variable what set `$baseUrl` in `lib/Zend/Controller/Request/Http.php` on `setBaseUrl` function.

I am new to the forum.  We do not want to modify the core.  Is this where I should report the bug?  If not, please help.

Comment: Please read https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/192917/46249 ... if ot helpful please open new question.